# Need help identifying memory leak using express in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, memory-leaks

## The problem

I have a Node application running in ECS that seems to be leaking memory, as the memory is constantly growing and dropping at every deploy.

I made a heapdump and imported it in Chrome DevTools, trying to make some sense of it.

## Heapdump

There seems to be several 100 000 strings looking like this. The syntax looks like the express res.cookie syntax I have in my middleware, and also of course in the login route. The middleware I have that is checking if the user has a valid cookie, and refreshing it if valid. Since it would be running more often I think it makes sense if the middleware is the culprit, but I still can't make any sense of why it is leaking.
[image: Objects]

## The possible culprit? Middleware.ts

```
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import issueJWT from 'utils/functions/IssueToken';
import { getRepository, getConnection } from 'typeorm';
import User from 'entity/organization/User';
import { ApiResult } from 'utils/classes/ApiResult';

interface ICookie {
    name: string;
    payload: string;
}

interface ICookieRouterConnections {
    routeName: string;
    cookieName: string;
}

const authenticate = async (req, res, next) => {
    const userRepository = getRepository(User);
    const { authorization, cookie } = req.headers;
    let requestToken: ICookie = { name: '', payload: '' };

    // These are the tokens that can be issued with their corresponding routes
    const portalCookieNames: ICookieRouterConnections[] = [
        {
            routeName: 'admin',
            cookieName: process.env.JWT_ADMIN,
        },
        {
            routeName: 'customer',
            cookieName: process.env.JWT_CUSTOMER,
        },
    ];

    // Find the router the user is trying to access
    const requestedRouterName = req.path
        .split('/')
        .splice(1, 1)
        .shift();

    function throwError(statusObj: { message: string; code: string; statusCode: number }) {
        const apiResult = new ApiResult();
        apiResult.addError({
            message: statusObj.message,
            code: statusObj.code,
            request: req,
        });
        res.status(statusObj.statusCode);
        res.send(apiResult);
    }

    // Gets the value of a cookie by the cookie name
    const getCookie = (cookieName: string): ICookie => {
        const returnObject = {
            name: cookieName,
            payload: cookie
                .split(`${cookieName}=`)
                .pop()
                .split(';')
                .shift(),
        };
        return returnObject;
    };

    const routerCookieName = portalCookieNames.find(obj => obj.routeName === requestedRouterName).cookieName;

    if (!authorization && !cookie) {
        throwError({ message: 'Token not provided', statusCode: 401, code: 'tokenNotProvided' });
        return;
    }

    // If there is authorization header, use that
    if (authorization) {
        requestToken.name = routerCookieName;
        requestToken.payload = authorization.replace('Bearer ', '');
    } else {
        // If not use the JWT from the cookie based on which router the user is trying to access
        requestToken = getCookie(routerCookieName);
    }

    if (requestToken) {
        // Validate the token
        jwt.verify(requestToken.payload, process.env.APP_SECRET, async (err, decoded) => {
            if (err) {
                throwError({ message: err, statusCode: 401, code: 'internalError' });
            } else {
                const user = await userRepository.findOne({ where: { id: decoded.userId } });

                if (!user.isDeactivated) {
                    req.user = user;
                    // Issue a new token if the cookie provided was valid
                    res.cookie(requestToken.name, issueJWT(user), {
                        httpOnly: false,
                        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 24 * 3600000),
                        domain: process.env.COOKIE_DOMAIN,
                    });
                    next();
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        throwError({ message: 'Invalid token', statusCode: 401, code: 'invalidTokenProvided' });
    }
};

export default authenticate;
```

Comment: I see a `MemoryStore.sessions` object in the screenshot - that sounds suspicious…

Comment: @Bergi: I think you might be on to something. I have instanciated a multer.memoryStorage() outside the FileRouter class by accident. Sounds like a possible problem.

Comment: However. I still don't understand how this correlates to the res.cookie stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I think Bergi pointed me in the right direction.

This was a package "express-session" that was loaded in the router. Seems like the default memory store is leaky and shouldn't be used in production.

From the npmjs repository

> Warning The default server-side session storage, MemoryStore, is
> purposely not designed for a production environment. It will leak
> memory under most conditions, does not scale past a single process,
> and is meant for debugging and developing.